# Why I´m getting this error: Undefined variable recover?

Tags: php

I´m doing a basic recover password system. And I click in my submit button "sendRecover" I will sent a email to the user. But I have a form and I want to show the email of the user in the input name="email" so I have   `" /> but I dont understand why I´m getting this error:
 **Undefined variable: recover**

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['sendRecover']))
{
        $recover = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);

        if(valMail($recover))
{
            $readRec = read('admins',"WHERE email = '$recover'");

            if(!$readRec)
{
                echo '<span class="ms no">Erro: Wrong Email!</span>';
            } 
else
 {

            foreach($readRec as $rec);
                $msg = 'test';
                sendMail('Recover data!',$msg,MAILUSER,SITENAME,$rec['email']);
                echo 'Sucess, your information was sent to: 
                    <strong>'.$rec['email'].'</strong>';
            }

        } 
else 
{
            echo 'Email wrong!';
        }

    }
    ?>

    <form name="recover" action="" method="post">

        <label>
        <span>Email:</span>
        **<!-- ERROR:  Undefined variable: recover -->**
        <input type="text" class="radius" name="email" value="<?php if($recover) echo $recover;?>" /> 
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Recover" name="sendRecover" class="btn" />
        <a href="index.php" class="link" title="Back">Back</a>
        </form>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Because `$recover` is not defined which is exactly what the error message says. You need to find out *why* it isn't defined.

Comment: That error message should have come with a line number. Find out why the variable never makes it to that line.

Comment: @castis: I believe the OP added an HTML comment near the bottom indicating where the error occurs. It's inside the `<?php ... ?>` inside the `value` attribute of the "email" input.

Comment: Looks like you may have omitted some of your code from what you posted, because there is an extra curly brace at the end of the code. This is not likely relevant, but it could be.

Answer (score 2):

The `if(isset($_POST['sendRecover'])){}` is within which you define `$recover`. If the condition is false, then the variable does not exist.
One solution is to check if the $recover variable is set.
Try this -

```
... value="<?php echo (isset($recover))?$recover:'';?>" />
```

Answer (score 2):

The only time we see $recover being assigned is when the IF statement has been successfully entered.

The form though is invoked regardless from the {} placing and if $recover has never been initialized and you are invoking it - it will throw you an error

Suggestion for the form:

instead of `if($recover)` do `if(isset($recover))` instead

Comment: thats up to you to set an email properly and make sure it goes into your if statement - your asking why it returns error and thats the reason. To ensure it goes into the if statement you have many options: 1) make sure the URI that it came from is fromt he form, 2) make sure that all form have entry or 3) send a small tag saying input type = hidden so that a variable gets posted.

Comment: Thanks but I really dont find the error, I review the code at least 10 times and dont find where is the problem, this is shuffling my head lol!